# MCP2200 linux settings

Tags: linux, terminal

Im want to control MCP2200 in linux.

I found [Text Link](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/mcp2200_linux_driver_readme.txt) and set everything.

For example:
I type in console

```
GP3-1
```

It will sets pin 3 to 1. But i dont know what to type in console

Answer (score 5, accepted):

for controlling the mcp2200 you will need a program doing the stuff for you.

The USBtoUART didn't work for me, maybe you'll have to do some coding yourself - but you can use it to understand how to connect to the mcp2200 hid.

For controlling the IOs, just set up a 16-byte array, filled with the data described here:
http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/93066A.pdf

If you want to control some more stuff but gpios, you'll have to do some more - it is possible to control more than just the gpios of the mcp2200 from linux.

I did a little usb trace of the communication of the windows config tool, extracted some informations and - tadaah, there you go with your own pID/vID, Manufacturer and Product strings.

Note: you'll probably need the HIDAPI MikeF was talking about.

First of all, some definitions:

```
// NOTE: max. string length for manufacturer / product string is 63 bytes!!

// from usb trace of mcp2200 config tool
#define MCP2200_SECRET_CONFIGURE    0x01
#define MCP2200_CFG_PID_VID     0x00 
#define MCP2200_CFG_MANU        0x01
#define MCP2200_CFG_PROD        0x02
```

... and some variables:

```
unsigned char **mcp2200_manu_string;
unsigned char **mcp2200_prod_string;
```

The output message for manufacturer string looks like

```
/* configure manufacturer string (16 x 16 bytes):
 *  output buffer:
 * #0: [01 01 00 16 03 58 00 4B 00 72 00 FF FF FF FF FF]
 *       |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  +-----------+--> Always FF
 *       |  |  |  |  |  |  +-----+-----+-----------------> Always 00
 *       |  |  |  |  |  +-----+-----+--------------------> First 3 Chars of Manufacturer Name / Product Name
 *       |  |  |  |  +-----------------------------------> In #0: 0x03, After #0: 0x00
 *       |  |  |  +--------------------------------------> (Length (Manufacturer Name) * 2) + 2 (after #0: chars of manufacturer name)
 *       |  |  +-----------------------------------------> Counter 0x00 .. 0x0F
 *       |  +--------------------------------------------> MCP2200 Config Bit (MCP2200_CFG_MANU / PROD / VID_PID)
 *       +-----------------------------------------------> MCP2200_SECRET_CONFIGURE from usb trace
 */
```

if you put all this in a function, it could look like this:

```
void prepare_cfg_strings (char* manu, char* prod) {
    char manuStr[64];
    char prodStr[64];
    unsigned int i, k = 0;
    unsigned char tmp = 0;

    memset (manuStr, 0x00, sizeof(manuStr));
    memset (prodStr, 0x00, sizeof(prodStr));

    // allocate mcp2200_{manu,prod}_string buffer, 2-dim array with 16 x 16 chars
    if (( mcp2200_manu_string = ( unsigned char** )malloc( 16*sizeof( unsigned char* ))) == NULL ) {
        // error
    }
    if (( mcp2200_prod_string = ( unsigned char** )malloc( 16*sizeof( unsigned char* ))) == NULL ) {
        // error
    }

    for ( i = 0; i < 16; i++ )
    {
      if (( mcp2200_manu_string[i] = ( unsigned char* )malloc( 16 )) == NULL ) {
        /* error */ 
      }
      if (( mcp2200_prod_string[i] = ( unsigned char* )malloc( 16 )) == NULL ) {
        /* error */ 
      }
      /* init the rows here */
      memset (mcp2200_manu_string[i], 0x00, sizeof(&mcp2200_manu_string[i]));
      memset (mcp2200_prod_string[i], 0x00, sizeof(&mcp2200_prod_string[i]));
    }

    // manuStr holds (strlen(manuStr) * 2) + 2 in byte[0] and manufacturer string from byte[1] on
    strcpy (&manuStr[1], manu);
    manuStr[0] = ((strlen (&manuStr[1]) * 2) + 2);
    // prodStr holds (strlen(prodStr) * 2) + 2 in byte[0] and product string from byte[1] on
    strcpy (&prodStr[1], prod);
    prodStr[0] = ((strlen (&prodStr[1]) * 2) + 2);

    // build manufacturer / product strings
    for (i=0, k=0; i<16; i++, k+=4) {
        if (i==0) {
            tmp = 0x03;
        } else {
            tmp = 0x00;
        }
        // manufacturer string
        mcp2200_manu_string[i][0] = MCP2200_SECRET_CONFIGURE; 
        mcp2200_manu_string[i][1] = MCP2200_CFG_MANU;
        mcp2200_manu_string[i][2] = i; 
        mcp2200_manu_string[i][3] = manuStr[k];
        mcp2200_manu_string[i][4] = tmp;
        mcp2200_manu_string[i][5] = manuStr[k+1];
        mcp2200_manu_string[i][6] = 0x00;
        mcp2200_manu_string[i][7] = manuStr[k+2];
        mcp2200_manu_string[i][8] = 0x00;
        mcp2200_manu_string[i][9] = manuStr[k+3];
        mcp2200_manu_string[i][10] = 0x00;
        mcp2200_manu_string[i][11] = 0xff;
        mcp2200_manu_string[i][12] = 0xff;
        mcp2200_manu_string[i][13] = 0xff;
        mcp2200_manu_string[i][14] = 0xff;
        mcp2200_manu_string[i][15] = 0xff;

        // product string
        mcp2200_prod_string[i][0] = MCP2200_SECRET_CONFIGURE; 
        mcp2200_prod_string[i][1] = MCP2200_CFG_PROD;
        mcp2200_prod_string[i][2] = i; 
        mcp2200_prod_string[i][3] = prodStr[k];
        mcp2200_prod_string[i][4] = tmp;
        mcp2200_prod_string[i][5] = prodStr[k+1];
        mcp2200_prod_string[i][6] = 0x00;
        mcp2200_prod_string[i][7] = prodStr[k+2];
        mcp2200_prod_string[i][8] = 0x00;
        mcp2200_prod_string[i][9] = prodStr[k+3];
        mcp2200_prod_string[i][10] = 0x00;
        mcp2200_prod_string[i][11] = 0xff;
        mcp2200_prod_string[i][12] = 0xff;
        mcp2200_prod_string[i][13] = 0xff;
        mcp2200_prod_string[i][14] = 0xff;
        mcp2200_prod_string[i][15] = 0xff;
    }
}
```

Call this function in your main loop:

```
prepare_cfg_strings ("MyManufacturerName, "MyProductName");
```

Open a hid handle to your mcp2200 and put this stuff on the bus:

```
// write manufacturer string configuration to usb device
for (i=0; i<16; i++) {
    hid_write (handle, mcp2200_manu_string[i], 16);
}
// write product string configuration to usb device
for (i=0; i<16; i++) {
    hid_write (handle, mcp2200_prod_string[i], 16);
}
```

If you want to flash the mcp2200 with your own VendorID / ProductID configure your message:

```
// Microchip VID: 0x04d8
//   MCP2200 PID: 0x00df
mcp2200_pid_vid_cfg[] = 01 00 D8 04 DF 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
                         |  | +---+ +---+--------------------------------> Product ID (bytes swapped)
                         |  |     +--------------------------------------> Vendor ID (bytes swapped)
                         |  +--------------------------------------------> MCP2200 Config Bit (MCP2200_CFG_VID_PID)
                         +-----------------------------------------------> MCP2200_SECRET_CONFIGURE from usb trace
```

and put it on the bus:

```
hid_write (handle, mcp2200_pid_vid_cfg, 16);
```

Have Fun!

n.

Comment: This seriously needs more attention.  Great work.  It appears that [several](https://github.com/julbouln/mcp2200_simpleio) [people](https://github.com/ipaton0/mcp2200) are using this for Linux-based config.

Answer (score 1):

You will not be able to control the GPIO ports from the console/terminal via USB tty...
The USB to serial/UART converter is one of the features of MCP2200, to control the GPIO, you need to send commands via USB & HID driver. to achieve this, you will need the following.

HIDAPI:

https://github.com/signal11/hidapi

USBtoUART:

https://github.com/Miceuz/USBtoUART

USBtoUART requires hid.o from the HIDAPI package.... so start with HIDAPI first...

good luck!

MikeF

ps: I made a few modifications to the code, to accept binary format for controlling the GPIO ports, etc... it has been compiled fine on x86 and ARM ( Raspberry Pi )